# How can i get the hashed part of url in Javascript ( new browser versions )?

Tags: javascript, routes

I want to parse an IE8, IE9 link in newer versions of IE , Chrome and so on.

Let's suppose i receive a link like this in Chrome :

http://mySite.com/myEvent?step=0#myEvent?requestNumber=mmmny98&stepId=1&_suid=543566456..

Chrome will convert this to :

http://mySite.com/myEvent?requestNumber=mmmny98&step=1 automatically and will set my step at 0 ( what it is before the hashed part )  .

If i use document.baseURI or smth like this i'll get the converted link .

I want to parse the non-converted link to get some informations from there ( set the current step and stuff like this ) .

Comment: Why would chrome convert a URL like that? You should be able to just look at `window.location.hash`

Comment: New browsers convert the hashed part somehow. The `window.location.hash` will be null after that .

Comment: What browsers convert the hash?  I'm not seeing this happen.  Are you sure your client-side web application framework isn't doing this for you?  Or is your server re-writing it for you?  I don't think this is a browser issue.

Comment: Was from History API . I found the problem now . Thanks for advice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get everything from the hash forward using:

```
document.location.hash
```

If you want to split out the `?` from the hash, you can do something like this:

```
document.location.hash.split('?')[1]
```

Of course, make sure to do some error checking... don't just index into the split array without knowing that that index exists :)

Comment: I can do that in IE8 and IE9 and i did, but newer version of browsers convert the hashed part, and `window.location.hash` , `document.location.hash` and so on will be null on the client-side .

Comment: I am confused by this.  The hash is a client-side concept.  Why would it be null in newer browsers?  I have tested this in IE10, Firefox (21 and 23), and the very latest version of Chrome (29) and it works.

Comment: I found the problem. Was from history API. In newer versions the history push the states, and delete the hashed part . In IE8 and IE9, there is not history API, the links remains with hash . Sorry for confusion . Hope you learned something new and didn't waste your time .